# Xcode Objective-C testing tools and debugging methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

1. How many testing tools available for iOS app development?
2. How to debug the memory leak?
3. What type of debugging methods available for Objective-C in iOS app development?

Comment: Just need to Google it -https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't what kind of testing tool you are talking but for code it's just IDE XCODE, for view you have some like spark inspector.
2. For memory leak you need use "Instruments", and when you select this tool you select "memory leak" type of analysis. You have other kinds of debug methods in this tool. Like I said even you think it's a different tools but it's all part of XCODE suit.
3. The same of 1 and 2 answer.